# How to check storm topology submitted successfully or got failed?

Tags: java, apache-storm

In my requirement I have to monitor the storm topology submission, means if submission got failed I have to resubmit it. As far I know `storm list` will give you list of all topologies but I am not sure how can it would fit in this use case.

I have to achieve this via **CLI**.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are running the deployment on linux, you can check the `$?` output after running the command.
- If it is non-zero, there is an issue with the deployment.